# cyrus imapd broken after server restore from backup

Tags: email-server, imap, cyrus

I had to restore a vserver with a running installation of cyrus imapd from a 24h old backup. After that, imap clients are timing out and the log gets flooded with the following:

tail /var/log/mail.info:

> Dec 24 20:59:16 h2229778 cyrus/master[3570]: service notify pid 10857 in READY state: terminated abnormally
>
> Dec 24 20:59:16 h2229778 cyrus/master[3570]: process 10858 exited, signaled to death by 11

Restarting via the init script gives the following:

```
./cyrus-imapd restart
* Restarting Cyrus IMAPd cyrmaster
find: /run/cyrus/lock': No such file or directory
find: /run/cyrus/proc': No such file or directory
```

with no change in behaviour.

I found lots of posts for both quotes, but not much that seems to be connected to my problem. However, my suspicion is that one of the cyrus databases got corrupted.

Might this be the problem?

How can I determine the actual cause?

If it is a database problem, how can I properly restore them?

I'm running cyrus 2.4.12-2.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

The lack of lock files indicates that cyrus is not working, it could be that the database has been corrupted.

You can try to repair DB using:

```
sudo -u cyrus ctl_cyrusdb -r
```

It does not show any output, buy you can open a tail -f to syslog to see what is happening.

It it fails, you can try deleting /var/lib/cyrus/db/* and executing the same command again.

It is a good idea to have a backup of all users in a text file, you can do it using this command:

```
sudo -u cyrus /usr/sbin/ctl_mboxlist -d > /tmp/mboxlist.txt
```

You can recreate the user DB from this file later using:

```
cat /root/mboxlist.txt | sudo -u cyrus /usr/lib/cyrus/bin/ctl_mboxlist -u
```

Note: All paths are for Debian, they may be different in other Linux distributions.